# Finding direction angles of a $3$D vector, with no points given

Tags: vector-spaces, solid-geometry

How can I find directions angles of vector $\vec{A}$ which lies in coordinate plane $yz$ and makes angle $15^\circ$ with $(X,Y, \text{ and } Z)$ axis?

I want to know how to find the directions if they make $15^\circ$ with the $3$ axes.

Please explain in details.

Answer (score 1):

> Find a vector which lies in the $yz$-plane and makes an angle of $15^\circ$ with each of the $x$-, $y$-, and $z$-axes.

Any vector that lies **in the** $yz$**-plane** must be perpendicular, at a $90^\circ$ angle, to the $x$-axis.

Therefore, there is no vector that satisfies all of your conditions.

Comment: Even if it makes angle of 15° with x-axis or y-axis?!

Comment: @CatfishFTW All vectors in the $yz$-plane are perpendicular to the $x$-axis ... It's not possible for the angle between the vector and the $x$-axis to be both $90^\circ$ and $15^\circ$ at the same time. Is it possible that you mean to ask a different question? Is this homework? Where did the question come from? Did you perhaps misread it?

Comment: Yes is misread it is with Z-axis or Y-axis, It is a question in my academic book yes

Comment: So, the question is to "find a vector $\vec{A}$ in the $yz$-plane such that the angle between $\vec{A}$ and the $y$-axis is $15^\circ$, **and** the angle between $\vec{A}$ and the $z$-axis is also $15^\circ$"? (this is not possible) $$ $$

Or is it this: "find a vector $\vec{A}$ in the $yz$-plane such that the angle between $\vec{A}$ and one of the $y$- **or** $z$-axes is $15^\circ$"? (this is possible, and there is more than one answer in this case)

Comment: The exact question: Find the directions angles of $\vec{A}$ which lies in coordinate plane $ZY$ and makes angle $15^\circ$ with $y$-axis. Same question is re-typed but $15^\circ$ with $z$-axis.

Comment: may you answer?